# How can this path stroke set the opacity of the group behind it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have this code which shows my current output when the snippet is run.

```html
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" enable-background="new 0 0 300 300" viewBox="0 0 300 300" x="0px" y="0px" xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" xml:space="preserve" version="1.1">
        <g fill-opacity=".2">
            <path fill="#f79820" d="M 150 0 c 82.8 0 150 67.2 150 150 s -67.2 150 -150 150 S 0 232.8 0 150 S 67.2 0 150 0" />
            <circle fill="#f5f4b7" cx="150" cy="150" r="141.9" />
            <path fill="#f79820" d="M 135.7 103.3 c 3.5 18.3 4 19 7.8 19.2 c 3.8 0.2 10.4 -4.1 13.6 -12.1 c 3.1 -8 5 -20.2 7.8 -27.9 s 15.4 -29.6 18.7 -39.2 s 0.2 -19.2 -3.1 -23.6 c -3.3 -4.4 -10.7 -4.4 -23.5 -3.4 c -12.7 1 -33.4 -0.1 -40.8 3.4 c -8.4 3.9 -12.1 4.8 -8.9 15.5 C 110.2 45.9 132.2 84.9 135.7 103.3 Z" />
            <path fill="#f79820" d="M 153.9 124.2 c -1.7 2.9 3.3 5.6 5.3 5.6 c 2 0 10.1 -2.9 23 -10.4 c 12.9 -7.5 49.9 -25.1 60.2 -35.2 c 10.2 -10 4.3 -22.8 0 -28.9 c -4.3 -6.1 -21 -22.8 -34.4 -29.7 c -13.4 -7 -16.7 1.2 -19.2 12.4 c -2.5 11.2 -12.1 31.1 -15.4 38.2 C 170 83.4 155.5 121.3 153.9 124.2 Z" />
            <path fill="#f79820" d="M 213.5 108.7 c -23.7 12.8 -50.5 24.7 -50.4 27.2 c 0.1 3.1 11.1 6.5 27.4 9.9 c 16.4 3.4 29.1 2.5 44.6 9 c 15.5 6.5 36.7 9.9 45 -5.4 s 0.5 -47.6 -8.3 -58.1 c -8.8 -10.5 -10.9 -15.1 -25.6 -3.6 C 240.8 92 227.6 101.1 213.5 108.7 Z" />
            <path fill="#f79820" d="M 283.6 167.2 c -2.2 -8.7 -11.1 1.4 -55.9 -8.5 c -44.8 -9.9 -60.7 -13.6 -63 -10.2 c -1.3 1.9 13.4 14.1 36 25.1 c 22.5 11 34.6 21.6 43.7 27.9 c 9.1 6.3 20.2 6.3 26.9 0 C 278.1 195.2 285.8 175.8 283.6 167.2 Z" />
            <path fill="#f79820" d="M 226.6 194.7 c -16 -3.6 -35.4 -19 -42.1 -23.8 c -6.8 -4.8 -21.2 -17.1 -25.4 -13.3 c -2.6 2.4 -0.7 15.6 8.4 38.7 s 18.7 56.7 21.6 73.6 c 3 16.8 10.9 9.5 19 2.5 c 8.1 -7 26.4 -21.4 40 -30.7 c 13.6 -9.3 11.6 -19 10.1 -21.7 S 242.6 198.2 226.6 194.7 Z" />
            <path fill="#f79820" d="M 157.9 178.9 c -4.1 -13.1 -5.2 -20.5 -9 -20.4 c -4.5 0.2 -9.1 18.7 -12.4 27.4 c -3.3 8.7 -12.7 52.3 -16.7 72.4 c -4 20 -1.8 25.8 15.2 26.7 s 36.7 4.9 42.8 -1 c 6.1 -5.9 5.3 -23.1 0 -44.5 C 172.5 217.9 161.9 192 157.9 178.9 Z" />
            <path fill="#f79820" d="M 135.5 171.9 c 2.5 -9.2 3.2 -13.5 -2 -14.3 c -7.1 -1 -17.5 10.5 -25.3 22.1 S 77.5 213.4 63 228.7 c -14.5 15.3 -4 23.8 16 36.2 c 20 12.4 27.9 13.8 31.6 10.9 c 3.6 -2.9 6.6 -26.3 11.1 -43.8 C 126.1 214.4 133 181.1 135.5 171.9 Z" />
            <path fill="#f79820" d="M 61.1 227.1 c 5.1 -6.8 32.2 -34.3 40 -44.8 c 7.8 -10.5 26.3 -28.2 27.9 -29.2 c 1.7 -1 -1.1 -4 -3.8 -6.8 c -2.1 -2.1 -2.8 -1.2 -11.1 0 c -8.3 1.2 -39 13.4 -53.4 17.7 c -14.4 4.2 -22.5 3.9 -31.1 7.5 c -8.6 3.6 -11.7 12.4 -1.7 26.8 c 10.1 14.4 6.3 18.9 13.6 28.9 C 48.9 237.1 56 233.9 61.1 227.1 Z" />
            <path fill="#f79820" d="M 25.8 169.4 c 9.1 -1 41.5 -11.6 59.2 -18.9 c 17.7 -7.3 40.9 -11.4 40.7 -13.9 c -0.5 -5.6 -29.9 -17 -40.5 -22.6 c -10.6 -5.6 -25 -19.9 -35.4 -25.1 c -10.4 -5.3 -23.3 -4.8 -25.4 8.2 c -2.1 12.9 -8.8 27.9 -11.4 48 C 10.2 165.1 16.7 170.4 25.8 169.4 Z" />
            <path fill="#f79820" d="M 54.5 88.3 c 16 5.4 37.5 19.7 43.1 24 c 5.6 4.2 31.2 20.9 35.2 17.5 c 3.4 -2.9 0.3 -21.1 -6.3 -31.8 c -6.6 -10.7 -9.1 -29.4 -14.5 -45.2 c -5.5 -15.8 -17.7 -28.4 -34 -18 s -33.4 24.8 -37.8 36 C 35.7 82 38.5 82.9 54.5 88.3 Z" />
     </g>
        <svg style="display: block; width: 100%;" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
         <path stroke="#f79820" stroke-opacity=".4" fill-opacity="0" style="stroke-dasharray: 157.698, 157.698; stroke-dashoffset: 55;" stroke-width="49.81" d="M 50,50 m 0,-25.095 a 25.095,25.095 0 1 1 0,50.19 a 25.095,25.095 0 1 1 0,-50.19" />
     </svg>
    </svg>
```

My goal is to get everything covered by the stroke to be shown "darker" than the remaining portion of the circle. However the effect that is happening is the opacity of the stroke is compounding with the groups opacity so it doesn't have the contrast it needs to have.

Ideally it would look something like this...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would inverting the pieces be an option? Instead of darkening the section, lighten the inverse? I removed the `fill-opacity` on the outer `svg`, changed the `stroke` of the inner `path` to white and increased the opacity to `.6`. I did not change the path, though, this was just to demonstrate the concept.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" enable-background="new 0 0 300 300" viewBox="0 0 300 300" x="0px" y="0px" xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" xml:space="preserve" version="1.1">
    <g>
        <path fill="#f79820" d="M 150 0 c 82.8 0 150 67.2 150 150 s -67.2 150 -150 150 S 0 232.8 0 150 S 67.2 0 150 0" />
        <circle fill="#f5f4b7" cx="150" cy="150" r="141.9" />
        <path fill="#f79820" d="M 135.7 103.3 c 3.5 18.3 4 19 7.8 19.2 c 3.8 0.2 10.4 -4.1 13.6 -12.1 c 3.1 -8 5 -20.2 7.8 -27.9 s 15.4 -29.6 18.7 -39.2 s 0.2 -19.2 -3.1 -23.6 c -3.3 -4.4 -10.7 -4.4 -23.5 -3.4 c -12.7 1 -33.4 -0.1 -40.8 3.4 c -8.4 3.9 -12.1 4.8 -8.9 15.5 C 110.2 45.9 132.2 84.9 135.7 103.3 Z" />
        <path fill="#f79820" d="M 153.9 124.2 c -1.7 2.9 3.3 5.6 5.3 5.6 c 2 0 10.1 -2.9 23 -10.4 c 12.9 -7.5 49.9 -25.1 60.2 -35.2 c 10.2 -10 4.3 -22.8 0 -28.9 c -4.3 -6.1 -21 -22.8 -34.4 -29.7 c -13.4 -7 -16.7 1.2 -19.2 12.4 c -2.5 11.2 -12.1 31.1 -15.4 38.2 C 170 83.4 155.5 121.3 153.9 124.2 Z" />
        <path fill="#f79820" d="M 213.5 108.7 c -23.7 12.8 -50.5 24.7 -50.4 27.2 c 0.1 3.1 11.1 6.5 27.4 9.9 c 16.4 3.4 29.1 2.5 44.6 9 c 15.5 6.5 36.7 9.9 45 -5.4 s 0.5 -47.6 -8.3 -58.1 c -8.8 -10.5 -10.9 -15.1 -25.6 -3.6 C 240.8 92 227.6 101.1 213.5 108.7 Z" />
        <path fill="#f79820" d="M 283.6 167.2 c -2.2 -8.7 -11.1 1.4 -55.9 -8.5 c -44.8 -9.9 -60.7 -13.6 -63 -10.2 c -1.3 1.9 13.4 14.1 36 25.1 c 22.5 11 34.6 21.6 43.7 27.9 c 9.1 6.3 20.2 6.3 26.9 0 C 278.1 195.2 285.8 175.8 283.6 167.2 Z" />
        <path fill="#f79820" d="M 226.6 194.7 c -16 -3.6 -35.4 -19 -42.1 -23.8 c -6.8 -4.8 -21.2 -17.1 -25.4 -13.3 c -2.6 2.4 -0.7 15.6 8.4 38.7 s 18.7 56.7 21.6 73.6 c 3 16.8 10.9 9.5 19 2.5 c 8.1 -7 26.4 -21.4 40 -30.7 c 13.6 -9.3 11.6 -19 10.1 -21.7 S 242.6 198.2 226.6 194.7 Z" />
        <path fill="#f79820" d="M 157.9 178.9 c -4.1 -13.1 -5.2 -20.5 -9 -20.4 c -4.5 0.2 -9.1 18.7 -12.4 27.4 c -3.3 8.7 -12.7 52.3 -16.7 72.4 c -4 20 -1.8 25.8 15.2 26.7 s 36.7 4.9 42.8 -1 c 6.1 -5.9 5.3 -23.1 0 -44.5 C 172.5 217.9 161.9 192 157.9 178.9 Z" />
        <path fill="#f79820" d="M 135.5 171.9 c 2.5 -9.2 3.2 -13.5 -2 -14.3 c -7.1 -1 -17.5 10.5 -25.3 22.1 S 77.5 213.4 63 228.7 c -14.5 15.3 -4 23.8 16 36.2 c 20 12.4 27.9 13.8 31.6 10.9 c 3.6 -2.9 6.6 -26.3 11.1 -43.8 C 126.1 214.4 133 181.1 135.5 171.9 Z" />
        <path fill="#f79820" d="M 61.1 227.1 c 5.1 -6.8 32.2 -34.3 40 -44.8 c 7.8 -10.5 26.3 -28.2 27.9 -29.2 c 1.7 -1 -1.1 -4 -3.8 -6.8 c -2.1 -2.1 -2.8 -1.2 -11.1 0 c -8.3 1.2 -39 13.4 -53.4 17.7 c -14.4 4.2 -22.5 3.9 -31.1 7.5 c -8.6 3.6 -11.7 12.4 -1.7 26.8 c 10.1 14.4 6.3 18.9 13.6 28.9 C 48.9 237.1 56 233.9 61.1 227.1 Z" />
        <path fill="#f79820" d="M 25.8 169.4 c 9.1 -1 41.5 -11.6 59.2 -18.9 c 17.7 -7.3 40.9 -11.4 40.7 -13.9 c -0.5 -5.6 -29.9 -17 -40.5 -22.6 c -10.6 -5.6 -25 -19.9 -35.4 -25.1 c -10.4 -5.3 -23.3 -4.8 -25.4 8.2 c -2.1 12.9 -8.8 27.9 -11.4 48 C 10.2 165.1 16.7 170.4 25.8 169.4 Z" />
        <path fill="#f79820" d="M 54.5 88.3 c 16 5.4 37.5 19.7 43.1 24 c 5.6 4.2 31.2 20.9 35.2 17.5 c 3.4 -2.9 0.3 -21.1 -6.3 -31.8 c -6.6 -10.7 -9.1 -29.4 -14.5 -45.2 c -5.5 -15.8 -17.7 -28.4 -34 -18 s -33.4 24.8 -37.8 36 C 35.7 82 38.5 82.9 54.5 88.3 Z" />
    </g>
    <svg style="display: block; width: 100%;" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
        <path stroke="#ffffff" stroke-opacity=".6" fill-opacity="0" style="stroke-dasharray: 157.698, 157.698; stroke-dashoffset: 55;" stroke-width="49.81" d="M 50,50 m 0,-25.095 a 25.095,25.095 0 1 1 0,50.19 a 25.095,25.095 0 1 1 0,-50.19" />
    </svg>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought about this but I am tying an animation to that path stroke that "fills up" with the dark portion until a certain point. For business purposes animating the inverse wouldn't make sense.

Comment: @Shoe Rather than starting with zero size and growing, couldn't you start with a 100% size and shrink?

Comment: From a coding perspective yes but from a business perspective no :) Even though the end result is the same the animation would show "shrinkage" when I want the animation to show "growth".

Comment: @Shoe Huh? No the visual effect should be completely identical. You were proposing two layers, the lower layer light, with the upper layer "darkening" that grows. I'm proposing you have a lower dark layer, with an upper "lightening" that shrinks.

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean. Let me give that a shot.

Comment: Worked out well. I just flipped my animation to work in reverse and now the opaque layer shrinks which gives the illusion of the dark layer growing. Thank you.